# EF Code first DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges deployment

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

EF Code first DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is a very nice feature for development, but what if I want to distributes my application to the customers?

There might be future changes to the database design.

What is the best method to deploy code first application using ClickOnce?

The database I am using is SQLSERVER CE or SQLITE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying applications to run on a users pc with their own database its useful to upgrade the database instead of just blasting it and starting again (which is easier for us devs).

Fortunately EF provides an upgrade mechanism called migrations. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621

This is available in EF 4.3+